# Can a 3g network work for this project and is my understanding correct?

Tags: android, unity, bluetooth

I want to make a game for the android phone using unity.  As you can tell by my last post i wanted to use networking to make this happen.  I decided unity would be a good choice and in no time i was able to have two android devices connect to a simple game using unity master server and i was able to see both of my cubes update in real time over both phones.

My end goal is to make a game where you are a sphere and your goal is to knock your friends off the the arena(A sumo game).  The arena will slowly get smaller until only 1 sphere is remaining.  My question revolves around how doable this would be with a 3g network over the phone.  It does not appear that unity3d has bluetooth support for android and i could not find a plugin for it anywhere.  This would be ideal to have bluetooth local networking and if i am incorrect, please tell me.

The way I understand cell phone data transmission is you have your cellphone and it sends the data to the cell tower.  The closer you are to the tower the better.  Does your relative position to one another(Two clients connecting ) matter if you are both in range of the same cell tower?  While my cubes updated just fine I know that 3g can be spotty.  Is 3g viable for this idea?  Is bluetooth usable for android with unity3d if not?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player proximity to each other has absolutely no effect, they will always go through the tower. Player proximity to the tower can have an effect depending on how close together towers are and how large their range is. As for connection speeds, I'm not sure how fast your connection really needs to go. 3G will generally operate at speeds of OVER 200 kbit/s. (This is the minimum speed specified by the standard, if a network cannot consistently get above this it isn't really 3G)

You can try metering your internet connection using a program like [this](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-download-upload-meter.htm) and running your game on your computer.

Hope this helps!